# How to create postgres database for Rails app manually?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rake

How can I create postgres db for Rails app properly but in psql, not via `rake db:create`?

I mean, one can always write `CREATE DATABASE project_name`, but I don't know what happens in that rake task under the hood. Maybe there are a lot of additional `params`.

**Update**

After first answer I decided to clarify: I know how to write and use migrations, they are awesome, but my question not about them. It's about `rake db:create` task and `pg` adapter.

In other words, I just want to know which command in `psql` is equal to `rake db:create`.

Comment: You can look in [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f47b4236e089b07cb683ee9b7ff8b06111a0ec10/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake) for `rake db:create`

Comment: If you don't trust the rake db:migrate, then why trust the Rails ActiveRecord component, or anything else? Part of the point of Rails is to abstract the data layer, so you're not writing db-specific sql code. This abstraction permits one to unplug and plugin a different database without changing model, view, or controller code. I understand the desire to be in complete control, but if you're writing psql code, you've just stepped back in time and circumvented the purpose of the MVC architecture.

Comment: I trust AR completely, and I use it's benefits: just yesterday I moved project from MySql to postgres, with ActiveRecord it is super easy. But when I set up server for that project I created postgres role for its DB (via psql) and I thought: maybe there is quick and safe way to create not only role but DB itself via psql, too? It is more curiosity than neccesarity.

Comment: @FlorentFerry thanks for the link. Quickly looked through code there, but it's too abstract. I just want to know which command in psql is equal to rake db:create command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select the db on pgadmin III it will show you the sql instructions with the local things to load. They are very importanst if you have full text  index on. You must run them from the database postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Rails expects table names to match model names but be plural and snake_case. For example, a User model will store records in a `users` table and a BlogEntry model will store records in a `blog_entries` table.

Rails expects a table's primary key to be named `id` and it expects foreign keys to match model names but be snake_case and end with `_id`. For example, if BlogEntry belongs_to User, Rails will expect the `blog_entries` table to have a `user_id` column.

Join tables (such as used with many-to-many relations) are expected to be named with the two models' names in plural snake case and alphabetical order. For example, a join table describing a many-to-many relation between a User model and a Blog model would be expected to have the name `blogs_users` and have, at the least, the columns `blog_id` and `user_id`.

Those are the basics. Of course, all of this is configurable: For example, you can use the `table_name` class method to tell a model to use a table with a different name, and the relation methods (`belongs_to`, `has_many`, etc.) all take options letting you specify different names.

Apart from these naming conventions Rails doesn't require anything special from a database, as long as the correct credentials and configuration are specified in `config/database.yml`.

Comment: Thank you for wide answer, but I know how migrations and associations work. But I do not know much about postgres.

Comment: You don't need to know much about Postgres beyond CREATE DATABASE and CREATE TABLE.